# Can not able to access the cookies which were created with local ip

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies, localhost

I have a java web application which is mainly working based on Cookies. I can open my application in the following 3 ways.

1. http://ipaddress:port/moduleName
2. http://localhost:port/moduleName
3. http://127.0.0.1:port/moduleName

If i open the application with localhost(2) cookies will be created and i can access the same cookies with my ip address(1)
but if user opens the application with loopback(127.0.0.1) ip address, i am not able access the cookies with my ip address(1).

Is this behviour coorect? I am assuming localhost and 127.0.0.1 is the same. Is it correct? I know cookies will be creaed based on domains.

Answer (score 0):

Note that **127.0.0.1 != localhost** for browser.

Browser will not send cookie that was set from **127.0.0.1** to **localhost**, because they are different domains.

Comment: Hello @Eghbal Sohrabi, Please read the question once again, i wanted the cookies accessble from 127.0.0.1 to my system ipaddress not for 127.0.0.1 to localhost.

Comment: Let me know if you have two computer! cookies saved in Computer A  just valid on Computer A , and you can't access that from any other computer. Describe your question with more details.

Comment: yes you are right @Eghbal, i understand that, but cookies created with http://localhost:8087/modulName are accessible from http://systemIpAddr:port/moduleName in the same browser..

Comment: Hello @Eghbal, Please let me know if i need to provide more info

Comment: @M.S.Naidu No, Now its clear and I don't know your answer. Because I test **192.168.1.53:8087/default.aspx**  and **localhost:8087/default.aspx** but they don't have share Cookies in the same browser I test it in both FireFox and Google Chrome.